# Checking for differentiability,partial derivatives of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as 
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
(x^2+y^2)\cos \frac{1}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}},  & \text{for $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$} \\
0, & \text{for $(x,y) = (0,0)$}
\end{cases}$$
then check whether its differentiable and also whether its partial derivatives ie $f_x,f_y $ are continuous at $(0,0) $. I dont know how to check the differentiability of a multivariable function as I am just beginning to learn it. For continuity of partial derivative I just checked for $f_x $ as function is symmetric in$ y $and $x $.  So $f_x $ turns out to be $$f_x(x,y) = 2x\cos \left(\frac {1}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}\right)+\frac {x}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}\sin \left(\frac {1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$$ which is definitely not $0$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$. Same can be stated for $f_y $. But how to proceed with the first part? Thanks!

Comment: You should compute $f_x,f_y$ at $(0,0)$ by definition.

Comment: They are $0$ . Then what to do?

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$
\begin{align*}
f_x(0,0) 
&= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{h^2 \cos \left(\frac{1}{h} \right)-0}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h \cos \left(\frac{1}{h}\right). \\
\end{align*}
$$
So 
$$
|f_x(0,0)| =  \left| \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h \cos \left(\frac{1}{h}\right) \right|   \leq \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h =0. 
$$
So $f_x(0,0) =0$.

Similarly $f_y(0,0)=0$.

To show that $f_x$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, we need to show that 
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} f_x(x,y) = f_x(0,0). 
$$
However, consider the path $y=0$. Then 
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}  \frac{x }{\sqrt{x
   ^2+y^2}} \sin
   \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)
   &+ 2 x \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right) \\ 
&= 
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  \frac{x }{|x|}\sin
   \left(\frac{1}{|x|}\right)
   + 2 x \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{|x|}\right) \\
&= 
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \text{sgn}(x) 
\sin
   \left(\frac{1}{|x|}\right)
   + 2 x \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{|x|}\right), \\
\end{align*}
$$
where 
$$
\text{sgn}(x)=
\begin{cases}
\: \:\: 1 &\mbox{ if } x > 0 \\ 
-1 &\mbox{ if } x < 0. \\  
\end{cases}
$$
Since $\sin\left( \frac{1}{|x|}\right)$ rapidly oscillates between $-1$ and $1$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ and it is not multiplied by any function $g(x)$ such that $g(x)\sin\left( \frac{1}{|x|}\right)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$, $f_x$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

We have a similar argument for the continuity of $f_y$ at $(0,0)$.

Comment: This is only one part of the question

Comment: @ZacharySelk I just saw that. Thanks. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\frac{\partial f(0,0)}{\partial y}=\lim_{h\to 0}h\cos\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)=0$$ since $|h\cos\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)|\le |h|$ which tends to $0$

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the answer by @MeeSeongIm, the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ are $\partial_x f(0,0) = 0$ and $\partial_y f(0,0) = 0$.

The only candidate for the differential at $(0,0)$ is: $$Df(0,0) = \begin{bmatrix} \partial_x f(0,0) & \partial_y f(0,0)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
which is simply the zero-functional.

We have:

\begin{align}\lim_{(h_1,h_2) \to (0,0)}\frac{\left|f(h_1,h_2) - f(0,0) - Df(0,0)(h_1,h_2)\right|}{\|(h_1,h_2)\|} &= \lim_{(h_1,h_2) \to (0,0)}\frac{h_1^2+h_2^2}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}\cdot \left|\cos\frac1{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}\right|\\
&= \lim_{(h_1,h_2) \to (0,0)}\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}\cdot \underbrace{\left|\cos\frac1{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}\right|}_{\le 1}\\
&= 0
\end{align}

Hence, $f$ is differetiable at $(0,0)$ with the differential being $0$, even though the partial derivatives are not continuous at $(0,0)$.