# Difference between sufficient and necessary conditions for a particular result in calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Lets say we have $z=f (x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\cos (\frac {1}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}})$ at $(x,y)\neq (0,0) $ and $0$ at $(0,0) $  we want to check total differentiability(TD) of $z$ at $(0,0) $ . Without using a formal theorem I opt for the sufficient condition to check TD which is to see whether $f_x,f_y $ are continuous at $(0,0) $ . Examining we see that $f_x $ is not continuous at $(0,0) $  using symmetry we claim that $f_y $ is also isnt continuous. Thus function is not TD at $(0,0)$ . However using the basic definition ie if $lim_{\delta p\to 0} \frac {\delta z-dz}{\delta p} $ exists then function is differentiable we see that the function is differentiable. Note that here $\delta z=f (\delta x,\delta y)-f (0,0) ,dz=f_x\delta x+f_y \delta y ,\delta p=\sqrt {(\delta x)^2+(\delta y)^2} $ . Why is this contradiction taking place? Also are there similar examples if we want to prove continuity and the function is continuous but $f_x,f_y $ dont exist?

Answer (score 0):

Continuity of $\partial_xf$ and $\partial_yf$ at a point $c \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is only a sufficient condition for the function to be differentiable at $c$, not necessary.

Let's recall the definition: $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c \in \mathbb{R}^2$ if there exists a linear map $L : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$\lim_{(h_1, h_2) \to (0,0)} \frac{|f(c + h) - f(c) - Lh|}{\|(h_1, h_2)\|^2} = 0$$

If so, then $L$ is unique and usually denoted by $Df(c)$.

There is also a theorem stating that if the partial derivatives $\partial_xf(c), \partial_yf(c)$ exist, then the only candidate for the differential at $L$ is represented by the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \partial_xf(c) & \partial_yf(c) \end{bmatrix}$.

We shall see that your function $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$. Let's calculate $\partial_xf(0,0)$ by definition.

$$\partial_xf(0,0) 
= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} 
= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{h^2 \cos \left(\frac{1}{h} \right)-0}{h}
= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h \cdot\underbrace{\cos \left(\frac{1}{h}\right)}_{\in [-1,1]} = 0$$

Similarly we see $\partial_yf(0,0)$.

We conclude that the only candidate for $Df(0,0)$ is:

$$Df(0,0) = \begin{bmatrix} \partial_x f(0,0) & \partial_y f(0,0)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

So, $Df(0,0)$ is the zero-functional, if it exists. Let's check in the definition:

\begin{align}\lim_{(h_1,h_2) \to (0,0)}\frac{\left|f(h_1,h_2) - f(0,0) - Df(0,0)(h_1,h_2)\right|}{\|(h_1,h_2)\|} &= \lim_{(h_1,h_2) \to (0,0)}\frac{h_1^2+h_2^2}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}\cdot \left|\cos\frac1{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}\right|\\
&= \lim_{(h_1,h_2) \to (0,0)}\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}\cdot \underbrace{\left|\cos\frac1{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}\right|}_{\le 1}\\
&= 0
\end{align}

We conclude that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ an that the differential is given by $Df(0,0) = 0$.

In your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2516633/144766) concerning the same function, you have correctly calculated that:

$$\partial_xf(x,y) = 2x\cos \left(\frac {1}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}\right)+\frac {x}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}\sin \left(\frac {1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right), \text{ for } (x,y) \ne (0,0)$$

This, coupled with the fact that $\partial_xf(0,0) = 0$, shows that $\partial_xf$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$. The same situation is with $\partial_yf$. Still, $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

---

For an example where a function is continuous at a point $c$ but the partial derivatives $\partial_xf(c), \partial_yf(c)$ do not exist, consider $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x,y) = |x|+|y|$, for $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

$f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

$$0 \le |x| + |y| \stackrel{CSB}{\le} \sqrt{2}\sqrt{|x|^2+|y|^2} = \sqrt{2}\|(x,y)\|_2 \xrightarrow{(x,y) \to (0,0)} 0$$

Now apply the squeeze theorem to conclude $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y) = 0 = f(0,0)$.

However, $\partial_xf(0,0)$ and $\partial_yf(0,0)$ do not exist:

$$\partial_xf(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0) - f(0,0)}h = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|h|}{h}$$

This limit does not exist. The same is with $\partial_yf(0,0)$.